# IOS 6.0.1 Safari Scroll pdf in iframe

Tags: ios, pdf, iframe, mobile-safari

I am using my webpage to show a pdf from App_Data.

I using this html:

```
<iframe src=""  id="iframePDF" style="width:100%; height:93%;z-index:1;></iframe>
```

And `javascript`

```
$('#iframePDF').attr("src", responseData.TempPath + "#zoom=100&page=1");
```

The zoom isn't zooming the page and I cannot scroll.

Is there any workaround for this or a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to scroll using two fingers, which is not intuitive for the user. You can not make the area scrollable unless you know the size of the content, which you can't, because iOS doesn't tell you.

Sorry, friend, but then you'd have to look into a native or hybrid app like the solutions offered by Cordova (PhoneGap). It doesn't matter if the file is in .NET App_Data or anywhere else online.

The reason why it works in your browser is because it has a built-in file viewer which is loaded when you open the file in a new window.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the iframe in a width-constrained element of some kind then apply this CSS to that element:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch
```

Comment: unfortunately it does not.

Comment: This will in fact provide scrolling you need to give the iframe a specific pixel width/height then wrap it in a div that is constrained to the desired size of the viewport. I do this all the time. See example#1 on this page, they are basically describing the same thing: http://dev.magnolia-cms.com/blog/2012/05/strategies-for-the-iframe-on-the-ipad-problem/, sorry If my answer was not clear enough.

Comment: will check it out and will let you know. Maybe I should be using something more than the example you provided.

Comment: I didn't address the zooming, by the way, but it's my understanding iOS does not allow zooming in an iframe.